# SLI inactive after GeForce driver update

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-geforce, sli

I updated the driver of my 2 GeForce GTX 460 SE and now, the SLI is inactive, and the nVidia control panel doesn't let me activate it. The message (it's in french, so I translate roughly) says "For optimal 3D performance, connect your SLI compatible graphic card to a SLI connector".

I updated to the 285.62 version, and my PC works with Windows 7 64bits.

Can you help?